# Auto translate web page using google translate

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I have put Google translate dropdown on my website. It currently detects the browser language and set it to dropdown. I want Google translate service to automatically translate my articles into user language. Here is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout:
    google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT, gaTrack: true,
     gaId: 'UA-xxxxx-2'}, 'google_translate_element');

    }
    googleTranslateElementInit();
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Is it possible to use JQuery to init Google translate api call? I tried this function `googleTranslateElementInit();` but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use this code:

```
<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({
pageLanguage: 'en',
layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

display laguage dropdown where you want to display it

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

If use only some languages translate than use

```
pageLanguage: 'en',
includedLanguages: 'pt,ar',
```

Be sure to add in head tag